# Building array for consuming complex wsdl - PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am having some issues, and yes, i am probably out of my league, but I do this for learning.

I am trying to consume a SOAP service, and i cannot, for the life of me build an array that the server accepts.

WSDL is visible here:

http://metrolive.telenor.no/kapaks-facade-soap-web/services/KapaksFacade70SoapWrapper/wsdl

I can do this and it works perfectly fine:

```
 $tlf = new SoapVar(
     array(
    new SoapVar(
        array(
            'ns2:connectionNumber' => 12345678,
            'ns2:connectionNumberType' => "T",
            'ns2:requestedProduct' => "OA"
        ), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, null, 'http://web.soap.v70.kapaks.facade.metro2.telenor.com'
    )
), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, null, 'http://dto.common.v70.kapaks.facade.metro2.telenor.com'
 );

 $client = new SoapClient($kapaks_wsdl, $wsdl_options);
 $result = $client->validateProductSoap($tlf);
```

This produces this xml: (From wireshark)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org /soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:ns1="http://web.soap.v70.kapaks.facade.metro2.telenor.com"
      xmlns:ns2="http://dto.common.v70.kapaks.facade.metro2.telenor.com">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:validateProductSoap><ns1:BOGUS> 
     <ns2:connectionNumber>12345678</ns2:connectionNumber> 
<ns2:connectionNumberType>T</ns2:connectionNumberType> 
<ns2:requestedProduct>OA</ns2:requestedProduct></ns1:BOGUS> 
</ns1:validateProductSoap></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But, i need to request properties from the "address" node(Is it node?). I can not figure out how to map this into the array, i have been at this for days...

This XML works in curl: (Straigt from SoaP-UI)

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

  xmlns:web="http://web.soap.v70.kapaks.facade.metro2.telenor.com"  

   xmlns:dto="http://dto.common.v70.kapaks.facade.metro2.telenor.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <web:validateProductSoap>
     <web:arg_0_0>
        <dto:address>

           <dto:houseLetter>A</dto:houseLetter>
           <dto:houseNumber>12</dto:houseNumber>

           <dto:municipalityNumber>0000</dto:municipalityNumber>

           <dto:streetCodeType>V</dto:streetCodeType>
           <dto:streetName>Street</dto:streetName>
        </dto:address>



        <dto:requestedProduct>OA</dto:requestedProduct>
     </web:arg_0_0>
    </web:validateProductSoap>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The curl approach gives me an xml response, but i need the array/object that soapclient produces, to be able to pass it to the front-end view.

How can i produce a soapclient request that will request what is inside the address tag? Or make an array/object that is identical to what soapclient delivers?

Comment: Something like `DOMDocument::loadXML()` ?

Comment: Hm, this is to convert the curl-xml response into array/object?

Comment: Could you provide us the $wsdl_options? I'm trying to invoke the service, but it states that I'm not authorized.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for helping out. There are credentials in the options that i cannot disclose, i have this access trough work, and i am allowed to use it myself, but i can not expose the login/password... I know this may make things harder...

The WSDL itself is visible without auth

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround. At this point i don't care how its done, just that it is done. Still, if someone has the answer on how to do it the correct way, i would like to see it.

I am using nusoap thats is updated for newer php (https://github.com/econea/nusoap) , and i send raw xml with that.

```
    function adresse($kmune1,$street1,$hnum1,$hletter1)
                {
                    require '..\vendor\econea\nusoap\src\nusoap.php';



                    $endpoint = "http://user:pw@metrolive.telenor.no:80/kapaks-facade-soap-web/services/KapaksFacade70SoapWrapper";

                    $client2 = new nusoap_client($endpoint, false);
                    $client2->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
                    $client2->decode_utf8 = false;

                    $XMLrequest = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://web.soap.v70.kapaks.facade.metro2.telenor.com" xmlns:dto="http://dto.common.v70.kapaks.facade.metro2.telenor.com">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                   <soapenv:Body>
                      <web:validateProductSoap>
                         <web:arg_0_0>
                            <dto:address>

                               <dto:houseLetter>'.$hletter1.'</dto:houseLetter>
                               <dto:houseNumber>'.$hnum1.'</dto:houseNumber>

                               <dto:municipalityNumber>'.$kmune1.'</dto:municipalityNumber>

                               <dto:streetCodeType>V</dto:streetCodeType>
                               <dto:streetName>'.$street1.'</dto:streetName>
                            </dto:address>



                            <dto:requestedProduct>OA</dto:requestedProduct>
                         </web:arg_0_0>
                      </web:validateProductSoap>
                   </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>';


                    $result = $client2->send($XMLrequest, $endpoint, null);




                    $result=json_decode(json_encode($result));
                    return $result;


                }
```